# Does importing with (import ...) slow down the app?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Development, sorry if it's a dumb question. Android Studio uses `import ...` by default. I want to know what libraries does it import and does using `import ...` slow down the app?

Comment: Imports are resolved at compile time, and are only a convenience to the developer so we don't have to type out fully-qualified classnames throughout the code. It "imports" whatever is after the `import` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Import statements only exist in your source code to find the class references. After the compilation (at runtime) they don't exist. So they don't impact the runtime at all. So they can't make the app slow.

Answer (score 1):

No, the import statement doesn't actually do anything except for removing the need to qualify.

For example, if you didn't want to use the import statement for an arraylist, it is actually quite possible to write

```
java.util.ArrayList<Integer> foo = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();
```

But this would clearly be horrible. By inserting the line

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

You are indicating that in this file, `ArrayList` really means `java.util.ArrayList`